# How to advertise Bluetooth LE service UUID in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I want to connect two android phones having low energy Bluetooth therefor I have created a Characteristic UUID within a service UUID. One phone will advertise the service uuid and the other one phone will scan for the service uuid  but, I don't know how to advertise the service uuid. Please guide me that how can I accomplish the task. Here is my sample code.

```
UUID serviceUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
UUID characteristicUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
UUID descriptorUUID = UUID.randomUUID();


BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(characteristicUUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
characteristic.setValue(77, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);

BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(descriptorUUID,     BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ);

characteristic.addDescriptor(descriptor);

BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(serviceUUID,     BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
service.addCharacteristic(characteristic);

mGattServer.addService(service);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "advertise the service uuid"?

Comment: Dear! how can I make visible the service uuid for other device that other devices could read/write the characteristic uuid within the service uuid.